# python requests: find downloaded csv file metadata

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, metadata

Downloaded `.csv` file from [this link](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv), from windows file explorer "Date modified" column I can see when the file is last modified (and it is not when I download it).

Now using `requests` lib of `python`, I can easily download the `.csv` file *content*. But how to know the Date modified metadata of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import requests

csv_file_url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv"
r = requests.get(csv_file_url)
print(r.headers.get('Last-Modified'))
```

> The Last-Modified response HTTP header contains the date and time at which the origin server believes the resource was last modified. It is used as a validator to determine if a resource received or stored is the same.

Output: `Mon, 28 Sep 2020 18:25:03 GMT`